# In C#, Is there a way to make an 2 element float array equal to a Unity Vector2 variable

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am coming for javascript and I just started relearning c# and Unity and came across a problem with arrays and Vector2 Variable.

I want to set a Vector2 varibale to an array like.

```
private float[] speeds = new float[2];
velocity = new Vector2(speeds);
```

When I try to run this code it shows me an error that says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Vector2.Vector2(float, float)'. I know what the problem is but I don't know if there is any way to fix it by still using an array

Comment: I imagine you'll need to write a conversion method.

Comment: @Ian Halstead Couldn't you just do something like `velocity = new Vector2(speeds[0], speeds[1]);`

Answer (score 2):

So I'm really stupid. I'm so used to javascript and web development that I do everything in arrays when I don't have too. It is much simpler to just use velocity.x and velocity.y
Thanks for the quick responces everyone and sorry to waste your time